# Image manipulation

Tags: java, image, geospatial

I am just wondering what kind of computing/programming language/frameworks are needed to produce images such as the one in http://www.erdas.com/ ?

Programmatically, how does one produce the general spatial analysis images ?

ps: I use java most of the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, uDIG, OpenJUMP (not sure about this) cannot process images in a way that ERDAS can. These softwares are great, but they do not have extensive raster funcionality.

You need to take a look at GDAL, which covers a bunch of languages and can manipulate imagery.

http://www.gdal.org/

As we speak the PostGIS team is building most of PostGIS WKT Raster funcionality on top of GDAL. It is a fantastic tool and consolidated library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which image do you mean, but geospatial images can be manipulated by software called GIS. Examples in Java are:

- [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/)
- [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/)

and a spatial manipulation library:

- [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/)

Comment: +1 for OpenJump - It's a great tool (if you don't overload too much maps in it). :-)

Comment: I had problems with some Shapes in OpenJump and with some others in uDig, but in combination both programs always worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the imagery from a provider and then you analyze it with various tools. For raster you could also look at sextante as a raster analysis library written in Java.

The tools mentioned above are the two best Java Desktop options unless you speak spanish and then I would reccomend gvSIG.